# How to Prevent Potential Leak of an Object when Casting the Result of ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat with __bridge to Create a UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, core-foundation

I've been using the following code to get the thumbnail image from an address book contact into a `UIImage`. However, the code gives a Core Foundation warning, *potential leak of an object*:

```
// Potential leak of an object

- (UIImage*)contactPictureForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    if (person != nil && ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
        return [UIImage imageWithData:(__bridge NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

How should I prevent the potential leak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with my code: `ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat` returns a `CFDataRef`, which is not being released. That's the potential leak.

Core Foundation objects are not automatically handled by ARC. From the docs:

> The compiler does not automatically manage the lifetimes of Core Foundation objects; you must call CFRetain and CFRelease (or the corresponding type-specific variants) as dictated by the Core Foundation memory management rules

**As one solution**, I could separate the code out as follows, so that I can release the `CFDataRef` with a call to `CFRelease`:

```
- (UIImage*)contactPictureForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    if (person != nil && ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
        CFDataRef imageDataRef = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:(__bridge NSData*)imageDataRef];
        CFRelease(imageDataRef);
        return image;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Note that the code uses *bridging* in order to cast between an Objective-C and a Core Foundation object.

A plain `__bridge` (like used above) does the cast without being concerned with ownership of the object.

**As another solution**, I could switch that to use `__bridge_transfer` - which does the cast *and* transfers ownership to ARC; ARC will handle the release for me. E.g.

```
- (UIImage*)contactPictureForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    if (person != nil && ABPersonHasImageData(person)) {
        return [UIImage imageWithData:(__bridge_transfer NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

If you're using Core Foundation, it's worth reading Apple's docs on these topics.

Managing Toll-Free Bridging is covered in the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW1).

And there's also the [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127i).